Power Automate Flow - Send an email if a SharePoint 'Proposal Date' Column = the current month
I have a SharePoint list with a proposal date column (SP column name is ProposalDate).  I want to manually run a flow that will query the entire list, identify items with a Proposal Date this current month, and send an email on those items.  I haven't been successful with the filter query on my Get Items.  So I'm hoping someone can help me get this set up.  The date format in SP is dd-MM-yyyy.  So if an item has a Proposal Date of say 05/15/2024 or 05/30/2024, I want to send an email.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks

What if proposal date is from same month but in the past, do you want to send an email for this case OR send email for future dates from current month only? Example: 3 May 2024.

Good question.  I would still want the flow to pick up that date and send an email.  I'd want it to query the entire list and pull any items with a May proposal Date.  Then send an email on those items

In Power Automate, store start and end of current months date and then filter the list in GetItems using those two dates. See the screenshots below

startOfMonth(utcNow())

subtractFromTime(addToTime(variables('CurrentMonthStartDT'),1,'month'),1,'second')


Updated the current month's Start and End Date Variables to send just Date values
CurrentMonthStartDT: substring(startOfMonth(utcNow()), 0,10)
CurrentMonthEndDT: substring(subtractFromTime(addToTime(variables('CurrentMonthStartDT'),1,'month'),1,'second'), 0, 10)


Thanks!  I ended up with an error though - "unable to process template language expressions in action 'initialize variable 2' inputs at line '0' and column '0': The template language function 'subtractFromTime' expects a timestamp as the first parameter, and interval as the second parameter, a time unit as the third parameter, and an optional format string as the fourth parameter.  The function was invoked with '1' parameter(s)

Can you post your expression? I think you have some parenthesis issue.  Or check here how this function to be added to expressions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/workflow-definition-language-functions-reference#addToTime

Also, check the variable name in your expresssion subtractFromTime(addToTime(variables('CurrentMonthStartDT'),1,'month'),1,'second')

Okay you were right that I had a parenthesis issue.  Fixed it and ran it again.  Didn't receive an error on the two Compose actions, BUT I did get an error on my Get Items filter query.  My Due Date column is date only, so this is the error I got: "The expression "ProposedDate gt '2024-05-01T00:00:00.0000000Z' and ProposedDate It '2024-05-31T23:59:590000000Z" is not valid.

You can use substring() function to just get the date values and store in the same variables. see the updated expressions. Mine date time field is set to show just Date, but stilled worked

Okay it looks like those two actions successfully returned the dates, but I got another error on my Get items filter query: "The expression "ProposalDate gt '2024-05-01' and ProposalDate It '2024-05-31'" is not valid.

Not sure why it would through this error for your PA flow. It's working for me when I have the value in date as well as in date time for ProposalDate column being date and time. What is your SharePoint Local settings?
